# Python: how can I ingest arguments from JSON file?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, argparse

I have a block of python code that ingests command-line arguments, e.g.:

```
import argparse
if __name__ == "__main__":                # myScript.py
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--int", help="Int with default", type=int, default=20)
    parser.add_argument("-swd", "--strwdef", help="string with default", type=str, default="DEFAULTSTRING")
    parser.add_argument("-snd", "--strnodef", help="string without default", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--flag", help="binary flag", action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    i = args.i
    swd = args.swd
    snd = args.snd
    f = args.flag
```

So this would work for a command like this:

```
python myScript.py -swd SomeString --int 35 -f
```

I want to read these arguments from a JSON file instead. Questions:

1. Are there built-in capabilities in `python 2.7` to set this up, instead of writing my own custom code of parsing results of `json.load()` to handle argument types, defaults etc?
2. If there is, what would be the proper format for a JSON file for the example above, and the way to populate the variables `i`, `swd`, etc?

Thank you!

Comment: For json validation you could have a look at Cerberus http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/latest/

Comment: Is the JSON the commandline values, or the parser argument definitions?

Comment: @hpaulj commandline values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` from the parser is an `argparse.Namespace` object, with is easily turned into a dictionary with

```
 vars(args)
```

`-swd SomeString --int 35 -f` would then produce something like `namespace(swd='SomeString', int=35, f=True)`, and `{'swd':'SomeString', 'int':35, 'f':True}`.

The equivalent JSON would decode to a similar dictionary.

A dictionary can be turned (back) into a namespace with:

```
In [2]: dd={'swd':'SomeString', 'int':35, 'f':True}
In [3]: dd
Out[3]: {'f': True, 'int': 35, 'swd': 'SomeString'}
In [4]: argparse.Namespace(**dd)
Out[4]: Namespace(f=True, int=35, swd='SomeString')
```

As far as I know there isn't a package that would apply `argparse` like reasoning to a dictionary (which may have been created by `json.loads`).

Someone else recently asked if there was a way of recreating the `sys.argv` string based on a `namespace`.  You might look that up.

I can recreate a `sys.argv` like list with this code

```
In [22]: def foo(k,v):
    if len(k)==1:
        k =  '-'+k
    else:
        k = '--'+k
    if isinstance(v,bool):
        return (k,)
    else:
        return k,str(v)
   ....:     
In [23]: argv=[]
In [24]: for k,v in dd.items():
    argv.extend(foo(k,v))
   ....:     
In [25]: argv
Out[25]: ['-f', '--int', '35', '--swd', 'SomeString']
```

This could then be passed to your parser with:

```
args = parser.parse_args(argv)
```

========================

Another thing you could do is create a dictionary with the default values, and update it from the JSON dictionary:

```
In [27]: defaultd=dict(int=20, strwdef='DEFAULTSTRING',snd=None,flag=False)
In [28]: defaultd
Out[28]: {'strwdef': 'DEFAULTSTRING', 'snd': None, 'int': 20, 'flag': False}
In [29]: defaultd.update(dd)
In [30]: defaultd
Out[30]: 
{'strwdef': 'DEFAULTSTRING',
 'f': True,
 'flag': False,
 'swd': 'SomeString',
 'snd': None,
 'int': 35}
```

I just noticed a problem.  For `defaultd` I used the long name 'flag' name, but in the JSON dict I used the short 'f' name.

I could selectively copy from the JSON dict with something like:

```
In [32]: for k in defaultd:
   ....:     if k in dd:
   ....:         defaultd[k]=dd[k]
   ....:         
In [33]: defaultd
Out[33]: {'strwdef': 'DEFAULTSTRING', 'snd': None, 'int': 35, 'flag': False}
```

Dealing with 'bad' values or aliases will be more complicated.

Comment: `As far as I know there isn't a package that would apply argparse like reasoning to a dictionary ` - That's what the schema library is for.

Answer (score 0):

So below is a way you can do that. I'm not sure how safe it is. The JSON keys should be the same as the variables that you need to parse them into for this to work.

```
j = json.loads(...)
print j  # {'swd': 'someString', 'i': 35}
locals().update(j)
print swd, i  # someString 35
```

The [docs for locals](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) advise against modification, so use this at your own risk.

A safer work-around that I quickly came up with is to store the results after argparsing to a dictionary. When importing them from JSON, just update that dictionary alone.